# Golang return function

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func findFiles() {
    filepath.Walk("/", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        fmt.Println(path)
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()
        hash := sha256.New()
        fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil)))
        return nil
    })
}

func main() {
    findFiles()
}
```

so what i am trying to do is return the hash when i call the function and i am not sure how.

I want it to visit all the dir and all the files in the system and than hash them and just print them out.

Comment: Hash of what file? You're walking a filesystem tree.

Comment: I want it go though all the files and provide a hash of all the files it finds.

Comment: "a hash of all the files it finds" --- what does it exactly mean, typewise? A single hash would be a string. What exactly you want to return?

Comment: i want a string of all the hash of all the files in the system

Comment: "a string of all the hash" --- this need elaboration. Every file would have its own hash. How would you get a single string out of it.

Comment: so when we hash a file i want that.

I want a hash of each file on the system.

Comment: When you hash a file you get a hash back. When you hash 2 files you get 2 hashes back. While you mentioned "a string of all the hash of all the files".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222042/discussion-between-prajwal-koirala-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func findFiles() {
    filepath.Walk("/", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        fmt.Println(path)
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return nil
        }
        defer file.Close()
        hash := sha256.New()

        if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return nil
        }

        fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum(nil))
        return nil
    })
}

func main() {
    findFiles()
}
```

Comment: The code seems to compile but the issue is its all the same hash for all the folders and the files.
https://play.golang.org/p/lq64XOH09NF

Comment: The `bin/*` files in the playground have the same checksum because they are all one single file, re-used. Note that some other files in the playground have different checksums.

Comment: Thank you :)

Been trying to figure this out for days.